# How to modify markers using javascript in gmap3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-gmap3

Using [Gmap3](http://gmap3.net/en/), I have a map set which shows some location but has no markers. Now how can I use javascript/jquery so I can add markers to the map? Basically I have an array with data, that I want to loop through and add markers to the map with that.

Thanks.

Comment: Link the Array, and show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used gmap3 but I think something like this will work.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245044/total-newbie-google-maps-api-v3-turn-markers-on-below-a-certain-zoom-level/16245123#16245123) out for a non-gmap3 solution.

```
var locations = [
    [47.003088, -96.929448],
    [46.817268, -96.810024],
    [46.842064, -96.796163]
];

$("#test").gmap3({
    map:{
        options:{
        center:[46.842064, -96.796163],
        zoom: 5
    }
 }

for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
   $("#test").gmap3({         
        marker:{
           latLng: locations[i]
         }
   });
}
```