# Display polyline when zoom is greater or equal to 10

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I have polyline with arrows and markers. How can I display that line when zoom is greater or equal to 10?

Comment: You really should provide your code to display the polyline if you want  an answer that matches your code.

Comment: @geocodezip. Will code snippet help you to answer this question? Code is trivial.

Comment: Didn't get why this question has been downvoted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Total Newbie. Google Maps API v3 Turn Markers On Below a certain Zoom Level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245044/total-newbie-google-maps-api-v3-turn-markers-on-below-a-certain-zoom-level)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

register zoom listener which hide/show a polyline depending on the zoom level:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  if (map.getZoom()>=10)
    polyline.setMap(map);
  else
    polyline.setMap(null);      
});
```